# Migrating a JDBC security realm to WildFly 10

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

I'm trying to migrate my security realm from GlassFish 4 to WildFly 10, following [this guide](http://wildfly.org/news/2014/02/06/GlassFish-to-WildFly-migration/).

I have:

- Set up my datasource as `java:/RemindersDS` and verified it is working.
- Set up my domain as follows:

  ```
  <security-domain name="RemindersDomain" cache-type="default">
      <authentication>
          <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
              <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/RemindersDS"/>
              <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT password FROM Authentication WHERE username = ?"/>
              <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT rolename, 'Roles' FROM User_roles WHERE username = ?"/>
              <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-256"/>
              <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="BASE64"/>
          </login-module>
          <login-module code="RoleMapping" flag="required">
              <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="file:${jboss.server.config.dir}/reminders-domain.properties"/>
              <module-option name="replaceRole" value="false"/>
          </login-module>
      </authentication>
  </security-domain>
  ```
- Verified the queries above.
- Added the *reminders-domain.properties* file in *configuration* directory with the following contents:

  ```
  user=user
  admin=admin,user
  ```
- Added `<security-domain>RemindersDomain</security-domain>` to my *jboss-web.xml*.
- Added the following to my *web.xml*:

  ```
  <security-constraint>
      <display-name>Update and delete users</display-name>
      <web-resource-collection>
          <web-resource-name>Users</web-resource-name>
          <description/>
          <url-pattern>/api/users/*</url-pattern>
          <http-method>PUT</http-method>
          <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <auth-constraint>
          <description/>
          <role-name>admin</role-name>
          <role-name>user</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <login-config>
      <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
      <realm-name>RemindersDomain</realm-name>
  </login-config>
  <security-role>
      <description/>
      <role-name>admin</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
      <description/>
      <role-name>user</role-name>
  </security-role>
  ```

The application deploys successfully, but whenever I try to do a constrained request, I get a 401 Unauthorized response. I'm using Postman to send these requests (and generate the header for HTTP basic authentication).

What am I missing here? What can I do to debug this problem? WildFly's log isn't reporting any issues.

Comment: You can set the debug level in the security domain to true for better logging. Looks like the problem was solved anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out hashEncoding had to be "hex". I wrongly assumed BASE64 referred to the BASE64 encoding used in HTTP Basic Authentication, but that wasn't the case.

Comment: in general, one should enable DEBUG logs for `org.jboss.security` category to see what is happening with security modules